# How to use a variable with a '.' in Text::Template

Tags: perl

How do I use a template variable with a '.' when using [`Text::Template`](https://metacpan.org/module/Text%3a%3aTemplate),

afile.xml.template ..

```
<m:properties>
  <d:Name>firstname</d:Name>
  <d:Value>{$user.firstname}</d:Value>
 </m:properties>
```

Templating code -

```
my $text = $payload_template->fill_in(HASH => \%properties);
```

`%properties` hash has the property "user.firstname" as "john"

This gives the output as -

```
<m:properties>
  <d:Name>firstname</d:Name>
  <d:Value>$userfirstname</d:Value>
 </m:properties>
```

expected output -

```
<m:properties>
  <d:Name>firstname</d:Name>
  <d:Value>john</d:Value>
 </m:properties>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the code fragment treats the `.` as a concatenation operation.

Try the following:

```
<d:Value>{${'user.firstname'}}</d:Value>
```